# Cannot import personal python module (installed with pip -e) from outside the module's directory

Tags: python, pip

I am developing a package for internal use, and said package has a `setup.py` file (see below). I am a bit baffled because when I install my package (inside an environment & in editable mode so changes get reflected as I develop it), the import works if I am in the development directory, but says "package not found" from any other directory.
Moreover, `pip list` shows the package.

To install, I do the following:

```sh
~ > cd path/to/package
package > conda activate env
package (env) > pip install -e .
```

The package installs. Now, the problem is

```sh
package (env) > python -c "import mypackage" # works!
package (env) > cd
~ (env) > python -c "import mypackage" # error!
~ (env) > pip list | grep "mypackage"
mypackage 0.1.0
```

What's happening? Documentation says

> -e, --editable <path/url>
>
> Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools “develop mode”) from a local project path or a VCS url.

Which doesn't really tell me that it should only work in said local project path...

### setup.py

```py
import os
import sys

from setuptools import find_packages, setup


def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

LICENSE = "MIT"


setup(
    name="name",
    version="0.1.0",
    author="organization",
    description="...",
    long_description=read('README.md'),
    packages=find_packages(),
    license=LICENSE,
    classifiers=[
        ...
    ],
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add where you have your module to the system path

```
import sys
sys.path.append(yourPathHere)

import yourModule
```

Edit - for clarity - the above goes into the .py that calls your module, not the setup.py that you use for compiling it.

Huh - I see your environment does see it with the grep. Prob disregard the above then!!